# Bash Script works but not in when executed from crontab

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I am new to linux and the script below is just an example of my issue:

I have a script which works as expected when I execute it however when I set it to run via crontab it doesn't work as expected because it doesn't read the file content into the variable.

I have a file 'test.txt' which has 'abc' in it. My script puts the text into a variable 'var' and then I echo it out to a log file:

```
var=$(</home/pi/MyScripts/test.txt)
echo "$var" >/home/pi/MyScripts/log.log
```

This works perfectly fine when I execute it and it echo's into the log file but not when I set it via crontab:

```
* * * * * /home/pi/MyScripts/test.sh
```

The cron job runs, and it sent me the following error message:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /home/pi/MyScripts/test.sh: Permission denied.
```

But I have given it 777 permissions:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi   25 Jun 10 15:31 test.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi   77 Jun 10 15:34 test.sh
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure to put the shebang on top.  Like `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: How often do you want it to execute? Every minute?

Comment: If it couldn't open the file you would get an error message emailed to you.

Comment: /bin/sh: 1: /home/pi/MyScripts/test.sh: Permission denied. But I have given this file 777 permissions.

Comment: @user3726871 Edit it into your question.

Comment: Do you have +x on all the directories leading up to the script?

Comment: @JakeGould You're assuming the cron job runs as `pi`. Why would no shebang give a "Permission denied" error executing the script?

Comment: Whatever other problems you may have, 0777 is always wrong, and a security risk. Sane permissions for this would be e.g 0755.

Comment: @JakeGould You need +x on all directories leading up to execute a script, even if the script itself is 777 and you use absolute path. Also, the error is in executing `/home/pi/MyScripts/test.sh`. Not executing line 1 of this file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you run the script with a different shell. It's especially relevant for systems where `/bin/sh` is `dash`:

```
$ cat myscript 
echo "$(< file)"

$ bash myscript
hello world

$ sh myscript

$
```

To fix it, add `#!/bin/bash` as the first line in your script.

Answer (score 1):

Others have provided answers, but I will give you a big clue from your error message; emphasis mine:

> **/bin/sh**: 1: /home/pi/MyScripts/test.sh: Permission denied.

Note how the cron job was trying to use `/bin/sh` to run the script. That’s solved by always indicating which shell you want to use at the top of your script like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(</home/pi/MyScripts/test.txt)
echo "$var" >/home/pi/MyScripts/log.log
```

If your script is using `bash`, then you must explicitly set `/bin/bash` in some way.

Also, regarding permissions you say this:

> But I have given it 777 permissions:

First, `777` permissions is a massive security risk. If you do that it means that anyone or anything on the system can read, write & execute the file. Don’t do that. In the case of a cron job the only entity that needs `7` permissions on a file is the owner of the crontab running that file.

Meaning if this is your crontab, just change the permissions to `755` which allows others to read & execute but not write. Or maybe better yet change it to `700` so only you—as the owner of the file—can do anything to the file. But avoid `777` permissions if you want to keep your system safe, stable & sane.

Comment: 0755 is read and execute for group and other, not read and write (it's writes you want to block anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. In the first line of your file, tell what program you want to interpret the script

```
#!/bin/bash
...more code...
```

Or in your crontab, tell what program you want to interpret the script

```
* * * * * bash /home/pi/MyScripts/test.sh
```

In this option, you do not need to make the script executable

Comment: @JakeGould, are either of these two commands correct then? could it be fixed by writing #!/bin/sh at the top?

Comment: @JakeGould, I made the change.